# Authorizing and then using JWT Token with Auth0 React & ASP.net core

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, access-token, auth0, bearer-token

I am building a react application, using Auth0 as my oauth authentication & backing it with a ASP.NET core api.

From React, I redirect the user to Auth0, which I have setup a single page application application.

When the login is succesful, it redirects the user back to my React app with a code.

I then want to translate that code into a JWT token to authorise access of the backend api, This is where it fails.

After login, I use the Auth0 supplied example library and call:

```
   const { getTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
   ...
   var token = await getTokenSilently();
   ...
   axios({
            url: `/api/Folder`,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
   })
```

it does provide a token but the token seems too small for a JWT Token, it looks something like this in the header:

`Authorization: Bearer 7hExNvsOM14TpY0qUnPbVqpizwLLxynw`

The response from my C# asp.net core api is:

`www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token"`

My C# Code looks like this:
startup.cs

```
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = Configuration["Auth0:Authority"];
        options.Audience = Configuration["Auth0:Audience"];
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier
        };
    });

    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true; //for debug purposes
    ....
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
```

folderController.cs

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class FolderController : ControllerBase
{
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That token you mention in your question is an [opaque access token](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/guides/validate-access-tokens#opaque-access-tokens).

> **JSON Web Token (JWT)** : Tokens that conform to the JSON Web Token
>   standard and contain information about an entity in the form of
>   claims. They are self-contained in that it is not necessary for the
>   recipient to call a server to validate the token. Access Tokens issued
>   for the Auth0 Management API and Access Tokens issued for any custom
>   API that you have registered with Auth0 will follow the JSON Web Token
>   (JWT) standard, which means that their basic structure conforms to the
>   typical JWT Structure, and they contain standard JWT Claims asserted about the token itself.
>
> **Opaque tokens:** Tokens in a proprietary format that typically contain
>   some identifier to information in a server’s persistent storage. To
>   validate an opaque token, the recipient of the token needs to call the
>   server that issued the token. Opaque Access Tokens are tokens whose
>   format you cannot access. Opaque Access Tokens issued by Auth0 can be
>   used with the /userinfo endpoint to return a user’s profile.

More info [here](https://community.auth0.com/t/why-is-my-access-token-not-a-jwt/31028).

To get over it... you need to setup your API project @ Auth0.

When calling Auth0 to authenticate your user, pass `audience` and `scope` accordingly.

`audience` is the friendly name you gave to your ASP.NET Web Core API at the time you setup it at Auth0 dashboard.

Here's a complete [step by step tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/how-to-build-and-secure-web-apis-with-aspnet-core-3/) for .NET Core 3.

Comment: This is the answer  was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to below article which provide detail steps for how to authenticate user and get access token to access asp.net core web api :

[Developing Web Apps with ASP.NET Core 2.0 and React - Part 1](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-web-apps-with-asp-dot-net-core-2-dot-0-and-react-part-1/)

[Developing Web Apps with ASP.NET Core 2.0 and React - Part 2](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-web-apps-with-asp-dot-net-core-2-dot-0-and-react-part-2/)

[Developing Web Apps with ASP.NET Core 2.0 and React - Part 3](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-web-apps-with-asp-dot-net-core-2-dot-0-and-react-part-3/)

In general , you should acquire access token while authenticating user with Auth0 in react application - set correct `audience` value which contains the unique identifier of the your registered API in react authentication configuration .

So that during authentication , user will be asked to grant permission to access the web api , if user consents , the react sdk will acquire access token and save to local storage in react application .